# Emploi de « RIP » (Resquiescat in pace)

Tags: usage, latin

Peut-on employer les sigles RIP (rest in peace; Requiescat in pace) pour signaler qu'une personne est décédée ?
De nos jours, y a-t-il toujours une connotation chrétienne ou pas ?
Par exemple, peut-on envoyer une phrase dans un message comme ci-après :

> Un article dont l'auteur principal est SA et les deux co-auteurs sont XY (RIP) et moi a été récemment accepté pour parution.

Comment: Conseil non lié à la question mais portant sur l'usage de *moi*: on dira plutôt *les deux co-auteurs sont XY et moi-même*.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais rencontré RIP, ni dans la langue française, ni dans les cimetières français.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il y a une formule moins neutre, mais qui a l'avantage de ne pas avoir de connotation religieuse ou "funéraire": *le/la/les regretté/e(s)*.

Cela implique que le décès de cette personne a laissé un vide, émotionnel ou professionel.

ex:

> Un film du *regretté* Alfred Hitchcock.

Answer (score 3):

On utilise de nos jours le terme « feu(e) », il est spécifique.

Un article dont l'auteur principal est SA et les deux co-auteurs sont feu(e) XY et moi-même a été récemment accepté pour parution.

« Resquiescat in pace » implique qu'il s'agit d'un défunt, seulement. De plus, cette formule s'utilise sur les tombes dans les pays chrétiens (Wikipédia); elle ne semble pas être utilisé dans le langage pour qualifier un nom.

ajout dû à @cl-r : « feu(e) » ne s'utilise de nos jours que pendant la première année de deuil

ajout dû au TLFi : De nos jours feu ne s'emploie que dans le discours jur. et officiel, ou par plaisanterie.

Comment: Feu : « Qui est mort depuis peu de temps », de nos jours ne s’utilise que pendant la première année de deuil. Une belle étude du mot et de son usage au travers des siècles : https://rouleaum.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/feufeue/

Answer (score 1):

Selon wiki on peut dire :

> Repose en paix

pour rendre

> Requiescat in pace

Effectivement, on pourrait même l'insérer dans une phrase :

> Un article dont l'auteur principal est SA et les deux co-auteurs sont XY (qu'ils reposent en paix) a été récemment accepté pour parution.

(merci @grouah !)

Comment: Effectivement, on pourrait même l'insérer dans une phrase : Un article dont l'auteur principal est SA et les deux co-auteurs sont XY (**qu'ils reposent en paix**) a été récemment accepté pour parution.

Comment: @grouah Merci ! Réponse actualisée:-)!