# Pourquoi le mot “regretté” se place-t-il avant le nom ?

Tags: sens, ordre-des-mots

When I speak of my late mother, I gather she’s not

> * ma mère regrettée,

even though she **is**

> ma mère défunte.

What’s up with that? Is there some semantic nuance I’m missing that accounts for this particular difference in word order? Maybe *regretté* is one of those adjectives whose meanings differ according to which side of the noun they occupy?

Comment: « Ma défunte mère » et bien plus utilisée que « Ma mère défunte », [NGRAM](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ma+m%C3%A8re+d%C3%A9funte%2Cma+d%C3%A9funte+m%C3%A8re&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cma%20m%C3%A8re%20d%C3%A9funte%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cma%20d%C3%A9funte%20m%C3%A8re%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cma%20m%C3%A8re%20d%C3%A9funte%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cma%20d%C3%A9funte%20m%C3%A8re%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Not answering to your question but in connection with it: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/31637/emploi-de-rip-resquiescat-in-pace

Comment: Voir aussi : https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_f&page=9wRyescDdDRo.html

Comment: @NGRAM, I'd even say that "ma mère défunte" is not correct, I don't think I ever heard or read it.

Answer (score 2):

This one is an exception to one of the rules about the place of the adjective, usually all past particle taken as adjectives are supposed to go after the noun.

**But** the exceptions are

- soi-disant
- prétendu
- ledit
- damné
- maudit
- sacré
- foutu
- fichu
- regretté (au sens de défunt)

And expressions:

- dévoué
- estimé
- vénéré
- etc.

*Source: Grevisse*

So you will say:

> ma mère adorée

but

> ma vénérée mère

---

This said, you will also find *ma défunte mère* and that even sounds more correct to me this way, to be honest.

Comment: Some of the them are strictly before the noun (prétendu, soi-disant, ledit), but others ones can be on either side, sometimes with a change in meaning like the OP mentions. *Café bouillu, café foutu... Gazon maudit...*